# How do I prove that $A\subset N^k$ is recursively enumerable if and only if $A$ is the domain of a recursive relationship

Tags: logic, recursion, computability

$A\subset N^k$ is recursively enumerable if and only if $A$ is the domain of a recursive relationship

I am trying to prove this equivalence for the characterization of an r.e set. I am working on the book "The Incompleteness Phenomenon" by Goldstern and Judah.

This is my definition for a r.e set, (the definition that I should use to solve the problem):

$B\subset N^k$ is said to be r.e if and only if there is an $\Sigma^0_1$-formula $\phi(x_1,...,x_k)$ such that $B=\{(n_1,...,n_k)\in N^k : N\Rightarrow\phi(n_1,...,n_k) \}$.

I try to attack the problem using the definitions, but I don't have clear ideas. When I try to understand how to handle r.e sets I always find developments using the theory of recursion from the perspective of computing (I found this proposition in my mathematical logic class); I would appreciate any sketch or reference to check.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is your definition of "recursive relationship"?

Comment: That is, the most general form of my definition would be: $B \subset N^k$ is r.e if and only if there is a $(\Sigma_1)^0$ formula $\phi(x_1,...,x_k)$ such that $B$ is defined by this formula. And B would be recursive if B is r.e and $N^k-B$ is r.e.

Comment: So putting this together, what you need to show is that $A\subset\mathbb{N}^k$ is $\Sigma^0_1$ iff there is some $B\subseteq\mathbb{N}^{k+1}$ such that $$A=dom(B)=\{(x_1,...,x_k):\exists y((x_1,...,x_k,y)\in B)\}$$ and both $B$ and $\mathbb{N}^{k+1}\setminus B$ are $\Sigma^0_1$, right?

Comment: Yeah, that's the idea.